# Search with pattern using argument placeholders

Tags: vb.net, resharper

I am using ReSharper 6.1 in VB.Net and I wanting to search for all the calls to `Help.ShowHelp` and put those in a wrapper.

So I have something like this.

```
Private Sub BtnHelpClick(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHelp.Click
  Help.ShowHelp(Me, HelpFiles.AuditTables, HelpNavigator.TopicId, AudittablesContext.AuditTables)
End Sub
```

And I want it turned into this.

```
Private Sub BtnHelpClick(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHelp.Click
   _navigation.ShowHelp(Me, HelpFiles.AuditTables, AudittablesContext.AuditTables)
End Sub
```

I tried something like this as the search pattern.

```
Help.ShowHelp($type1$, $type2$ , HelpNavigator.TopicId, $type3$)
```

- where type1 is an expression of `System.Windows.Forms.Form`
- where type2 is an expression of `System.String`
- where type3 is an expression of `System.Object`

I tried more things then I care to remember. But even this doesn't work `Help.ShowHelp($type1$`.

When I try `Help.ShowHelp(` it does find that, so I think it's the expressions that aren't matching anything.

Any help would be grately appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ***argument placeholders*** for *ShowHelp* arguments like so: `Help.ShowHelp($arg1$,$arg2$,$arg3$,$arg4$);`.
Every argument placeholder should have exactly 1 argument.
The replace pattern is: `_navigation.ShowHelp($arg1$, $arg2$, $arg4$);`

[image]

Now all *Help.ShowHelp* calls are marked as suggestions and can be replaced.